# Why doesn't the server receive messages from the client?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am trying to do a traditional chat server with some external functionality but the server doesn't receive data for some reason:

```
import socket
import select
import sys
import _thread


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
IP_address = "127.0.0.1"
Port = 5454


server.bind((IP_address, Port))


server.listen(100)

list_of_clients = []


def clientthread(conn, addr):
    # sends a message to the client whose user object is conn
    conn.send(bytes("Welcome to this chatroom!", "utf8"))

    while True:
        try:
            message = conn.recv(2048)
            print(message)
            if message:
                print("<" + addr[0] + "> " + message)

                # Calls broadcast function to send message to all
                message_to_send = "<" + addr[0] + "> " + message
                broadcast(message_to_send, conn)

            else:
                print("removed")
                remove(conn)

        except:
            continue


def broadcast(message, connection):
    for clients in list_of_clients:
        if clients != connection:
            try:
                clients.send(bytes(message, "utf8"))
            except:
                clients.close()

                # if the link is broken, we remove the client
                remove(clients)





def remove(connection):
    if connection in list_of_clients:
        list_of_clients.remove(connection)


while True:

    conn, addr = server.accept()


    list_of_clients.append(conn)

    # prints the address of the user that just connected
    print(addr[0] + " connected")

    # creates and individual thread for every user
    # that connects
    _thread.start_new_thread(clientthread, (conn, addr))

conn.close()
server.close()
```

And the client:

```
import socket
import select
import sys
from file_utils import client_message_observer as ob



def callback():
    print("message.txt was modified")
    return True

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

IP_address = "127.0.0.1"
Port = 5454
server.connect((IP_address, Port))
observer = ob.FileModifiedHandler("client_data/", "message.txt", callback())
server.send(bytes("aloooo"))
while True:

    # maintains a list of possible input streams
    sockets_list = [sys.stdin, server]
    read_sockets, write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list, [], [])

    for socks in read_sockets:
        if socks == server:
            message = socks.recv(2048)
            print(message)
            #write to file
        else:
            if (observer.callback == True):
                message = open("client_data/message.txt").readline()
                server.send(bytes(message, "utf8"))
                print("send")
server.close()
```

Not a single of the test prints appeared.

The code is not very clear it listens for changes in the message.txt file and when the file is modified it should send the text as message to the server. I haven't added the code of the observer but I tested it and it works. But I cant figure out why doesn't the server responds to the client?

Comment: `callback` means function's name without `()` so program can execute it later. But I see some callback with `()` in `FileModifiedHandler` - it means you execute `callback()` at start and its result (`True`) is used in `FileModifiedHandler` - you have `ob.FileModifiedHandler("client_data/", "message.txt", True)`

Comment: I fixed it but still nothing on the server.

Comment: when I run it on Python 3.7 - after removing `FileModifiedHandler` which I don't have - I see two error messages. First: it needs `"utf-8"` in `bytes("aloooo")`. Second: it can't concatenate strings with bytes but you can't see this message because you don't display errors in `except:` - and it is big mistake. Of couse I tested it on one computer because `127.0.0.1` can't be tested on two computers.

Comment: if you run it on two computers then you have to change `IP`. Server has to use IP of its network card or `0.0.0.0` to use all networks cards. Client has to use server's local IP if it is local network - or external IP of router which has to redirect port 5454 to server in local network - if it is connection from internet.